# Update a nth element in a sub nested document Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nested, document, updates

I need to update a nth element in a sub nested document:I have this structure:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("52fdbbb470c68c3c14d60700"),
  "curations" : [{

      "measurements" : 
      [
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("52fdbbb470c68c3c14d80700"),
          "name" : "GSM15729",
          "Vals" : ["N/A", "bronchus, lung", "bronchial epithelial cell", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "non-smoker", "GPL96"]
        }, 
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("52fdbbb470c68c3c14d90700"),
          "name" : "GSM104072",
          "Vals" : ["N/A", "bronchus, lung", "bronchial epithelial cell", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "current smoker", "GPL96"]
        }

        ]

    }]
}
```

And I want to update for example the 4th "N/A"(5th position) in the last sub array "Vals"

I tried with the command line this code but it seems not to be working

```
db.Series.find({"curations.measurements._id":new ObjectId("52fdbbb470c68c3c14d90700")},
    { $set: {
        "curations.measurements.$.Vals.4": "new_value"
        }
 });
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the error,just I forgot a zero...( array)

```
db.Series.find({"curations.0.measurements._id":new ObjectId("52fdbbb470c68c3c14d90700")},
    { $set: {
        "curations.0.measurements.$.Vals.4": "new_value" <=In this line
        }
 });
```